# Customize wubi installer?

Tags: wubi

I want to customize the wubi installer and change the ubuntu name and logo from the installer as well as from the add/remove programs menu.

Comment: This should tell you what you need to know: http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-installer/wubi/trunk/view/head:/README

Answer (score 1):

One of the easiest ways to do that is to use Remastersys. 
http://www.remastersys.com/ubuntu.html
 [image]

Comment: For Ubuntu 16.04 and Higher, Use Wubi by Hakuna Matata To Install Wubi on Windows Laptop/Computers without using a USB Stick.

**Wubi Hakuna Matata download from the wiki: [https://github.com/hakuna-m/wubiuefi/wiki]**

If you want to do other Linux OS, you can use Unetbootin or Rufus